# Mongodb returns one document per or match

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to returns in mongodb one document per match condition.
Let's imagine I have a collection with fields "name" and "firstName"

Then I am searching:

```
(name=John && firstName=Peter) || (name=Peter && firstName=John)
```

Instead of returning all the John Peter and the all the Peter John I would like to return only one John Peter and one Peter John

Thanks in advance for your answers

Regards

Comment: Oh! Do you mean one document of match `(name=John && firstName=Peter)` *and* one document of match `(name=Peter && firstName=John)`?

Comment: Yes totally !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You shall use [`findOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) over your query statement which

> **Returns one document that satisfies the specified query criteria on
>   the collection or view**

Sample mongo query:

for your example with *(name=John && firstName=Peter)*

```
db.yourCollection.findOne(
    { "name": "John", "firstName": "Peter" }
)
```

Comment: Yes I thought that. I just hopped to find another way :)

Comment: @Geoffrey Another way as in not using `findOne` and still getting just one document?

Comment: It is one document that match one condition

Comment: @Geoffrey Didn't get you there, if this is not what you desire, please edit the question to provide more details.

Comment: I think the question is clear :) I would like one query with or and returning one element per or. For exemple :  name=petter or firstname=petter => returns one petter (as name) and one petter (as firstname). Instead of doing findOne(name : petter) then findOne(firstname : petter) have everything in one command

Comment: The question is clear, he wants one result for each `or` block. I don't know if that's achievable with a single query though (or at least not without it being worse, performance-wise, than two `findOne` queries)

Comment: @lascort I think I need more clarification in that case. Thanks